# preparing data frame in r for heatmap with ggplot2

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2, heatmap

Currently trying to create a heatmap of some genetic data. The columns are currently labeled s1, s2, s3, etc., but I also have a .txt file that has the correct corresponding labels for each sample. I'm not sure if I need to first modify the csv file with the levels of gene expression or if I can transfer them separately to the data frame I'm trying to prepare that will eventually be made into a heatmap. I'm also not sure exactly what the format of the dataframe should be. I would like to use ggplot2 to create the heatmap if that matters.

Here's my code so far:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(magrittr) 

nci <- read.csv('/Users/myname/Desktop/ML Extra Credit/nci.data.csv')
nci.label <-scan(url("https://web.stanford.edu/~hastie/ElemStatLearn/datasets/nci.label",what="")
                 
#Select certain columns (specific years)
mat <- matrix(rexp(200, rate=.1), ncol=20)
rownames(mat) <- paste0('gene',1:nrow(mat))
colnames(mat) <- paste0('sample',1:ncol(mat))
mat[1:5,1:5]
```

It outputs a sample data frame that looks like this:

```
    sample1   sample2    sample3   sample4   sample5

gene1 32.278434 16.678512  0.4637713  1.016569  3.353944

gene2  8.719729 11.080337  1.5254223  2.392519  3.503191

gene3  2.199697 18.846487 13.6525699 34.963664  2.511097

gene4  5.860673  2.160185  3.5243884  6.785453  3.947606

gene5 16.363688 38.543575  5.6761373 10.142018 22.481752
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will want to get your dataframe in "long" format to facilitate plotting.  This is what's called [Tidy Data](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tidyr/vignettes/tidy-data.html) and forms the basis for preparing data to be plotted using `ggplot2`.

The general idea here is that you need one column for the `x` value, one column for the `y` value, and one column to represent the value used for the tile color.  There are lots of ways to do this (see `melt()`, `pivot_longer()`...), but I like to use `tidyr::gather()`.  Since you're using rownames, instead of a column for gene, I'm first creating that as a column in your dataset.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(1234)

# create matrix
mat <- matrix(rexp(200, rate=.1), ncol=20)
rownames(mat) <- paste0('gene',1:nrow(mat))
colnames(mat) <- paste0('sample',1:ncol(mat))
mat[1:5,1:5]

# convert to data.frame and gather
mat <- as.data.frame(mat)
mat$gene <- rownames(mat)
mat <- mat %>% gather(key='sample', value='value', -gene)
```

The `ggplot` call is pretty easy.  We assign each column to `x`, `y`, and `fill` aesthetics, then use `geom_tile()` to create the actual heatmap.

```
ggplot(mat, aes(sample, gene)) + geom_tile(aes(fill=value))
```

[image]

Comment: Getting the following error message when I try to use the gather function: Error in UseMethod("gather") : 
  no applicable method for 'gather' applied to an object of class "list"

Comment: @Kyle - apologies, I did not see at first you post that you have a matrix.  You'll need to convert first to a data frame in order to use the `gather` function.  I've edited the answer to reflect your particular case.

Comment: I actually ended up using melt() to convert the df to long format. Now my code is a bit simpler with just the libraries, the read.csv, head(melt(nci)), and then the ggplot to create the heatmap, but it's telling me no object 'value' found now.

Comment: Are you pointing to the right dataset?  `melt()` should be creating a column called "`value`", and for me it defaults to the column names `X1` and `X2`.  You might need to define the names of your dataset and be sure they match exactly the names that are assigned to each aesthetic (`x`, `y`, and `fill`) in the `ggplot` code.

Comment: @Kyle, I've answered your other question, but that's a duplicate of what is already here and what is already answered.  From your post there, you were using `ggplot(nci)`, which is trying to plot the "non-melted" dataset.  If you want to use `melt()` directly in the data call, you can use `metl(nci)`

Comment: Ok, yeah, having success with the revised code above. I'd like to choose 50 genes at random for the Y axis of the heatmap. And on the X axis I would like to potentially name the samples with the .txt file. Would you recommend I just go in and change the names within the csv file since there's only 64, or is there an easier way? Also, the names on the x axis are bleeding together when ncol=64 for all samples. Anyway of reformatting the sample names vertically so they are all legible?

Comment: Yes, sure.  If you're able to specify a clear example with the dataset you are working with (use `dput(your_data)` and paste the code that you get when you type that in the console), it would be easier.  But very doable and likely pretty straightforward to (1) sample a random mix of genes, and (2) reformat the axes text.  That is significantly different enough to be a different question.  You may refer back to this one, but if you ask that, just be clear on providing enough information to make a reproducible example.

Comment: If you want to give it a try:  (1) sampling can be done pretty easily via the `sample()` function.  Basically, filter your dataset via a `sample()` method as the input.  If you're going to do that often, write a function.  Otherwise, just do it in one-time code.  (2) formatting x axis depends on if you need to see "Sample #" or just the #.  If you need "Sample #" to appear, rotating text works fine (`theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle=30)` works.  Otherwise, pull out the numbers and plot with that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230608/discussion-between-kyle-and-chemdork123).